# How to block access to files in the current directory with .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a few private files in a public folder and I want to block access to them.
For example lets say I have the following files tree:

- DictA

  - FileA
- FileA
- FileB
- FileC

I want to block access to FileB and FileA in the current directory and allow access to the FileA in the DictA directory. The first thing that came to mind was to use the FilesMatch directive as follows:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?:FileA)|(?:FileB)$">
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The problem here is that FileA inside DictA will also be blocked, which is not what I wanted. I could override that by adding another .htaccess file to DictA but I would like to know if there is a solution which wont involve that.

P.S: I can't move the private files to a separate folder.

Answer (score 3):

You have several methods:

One would be to write a regular expression containing a `/` as stopping character.

Another one, allowing to use any options for Apache: you define the desired options for the current directory, then you define the opposite options for subdirectories.

```
<Directory /var/www/mydir/>
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/mydir/*>
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

So for your example, just use `deny` in the current dir, and `allow` for the sub-dirs:

```
<Directory /var/www/mydir/>
<FilesMatch "^(?:FileA)|(?:FileB)$">
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/mydir/*>
<FilesMatch "^(?:FileA)|(?:FileB)$">
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

mod_rewrite can do this.

```
RewriteRule ^File[AB]$ - [R=404]
```